# IFrame Responsive Site

Tags: php, wordpress, css

I have two responsive sites. example1.com and example2.com.

The example2.com is linked with example1.com using an IFrame.

Both the sites are responsive and work fine. But when I view the example1.com from my mobile devices the example2.com doesn't show up as responsive.

I think this has to do something with IFrame. Is there a way to link the site together so that when seen from mobile devices both come up as responsive?

One of the site uses wordpress and other is in PHP.

Comment: Have you applied a fixed width to the iframe? This usually causes the issue. Maybe apply a max-width:100% style to the iframe.

Comment: @msbodetti Yes I had the fixed width applied on the IFrame. Chaining that has solved the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Please remove fixed width to the iframe if you have given it. You can use % width to it.

Thanks!